# ID Or Class in CSS when overriding an Input type?

Tags: html, class, css

Can someone explain me the difference between using ID's (#imAnId) and classes (.imAClass) ?

And what i should use when i'm overriding the main style?

As for now I did this in my css:

```
input[type=submit] {
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    color: #444;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 54px;
}

input[type=submit]:focus {
    border-color: #cdcdcd;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    outline: none;
}

.searchButtonHomePage {
    display: block;
    height: 29px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.searchButtonResultPage {
    border-left: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    height: 32px;
}
```

Which i therefore only need to call the class when using a submit input type like this:

```
<input type="submit" class="searchButtonHomePage" />
```

Is this the correct sollution or not?
As i've heard also something about:

```
Don't use IDs in selectors.
```

Regarding CSSLint.

Greetings me :)

Comment: Not really as this is specific regarding overriding a default input type and what's the best way to do it, therefore it's not a duplicate :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference should be a ID is one specific element and class can be used for a lot of objects in the code, if you want too.

Its the last CSS rule in the code for some object which decide what a object will use as the rule for something.

Answer (score 1):

It is all about specificity. You can visualize this with the [keegan street](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548689/keegan-street)'s [specificity calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/).

In general, it is best if you don't ever use ids for styling, because it makes it harder to override it in the future.